# Can you configure Alpine's apk to be interactive by default?

Tags: package-management, configuration, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I find myself preferring the interactive mode that can be accessed by adding the `-i` flag when running Alpine's apk over the default non-interactive mode. However, it is rather tedious to constantly write e.g. `# apk add -i` over `# apk add`. Is there any way I can make the interactive mode the default mode of operation for Alpine's apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code of `apk` has this function](https://git.alpinelinux.org/apk-tools/tree/src/apk.c?h=2.12-stable#n416) that might be of interest.

```c
static void setup_automatic_flags(void)
{
    [...]
    if (!(apk_flags & APK_SIMULATE) &&
        access("/etc/apk/interactive", F_OK) == 0)
        apk_flags |= APK_INTERACTIVE;
}
```

`APK_INTERACTIVE` is the flag enabled by the `-i` option:

```c
#define GLOBAL_OPTIONS(OPT) \
    ...
    OPT(OPT_GLOBAL_interactive,     APK_OPT_SH("i") "interactive") \
    ...
```

And:

```c
static int option_parse_global(void *ctx, struct apk_db_options *dbopts, int opt, const char *optarg)
{
...
    case OPT_GLOBAL_interactive:
        apk_flags |= APK_INTERACTIVE;
        break;
```

I think this means the existence of the `/etc/apk/interactive` file automatically enables the `-i` option's behaviour. I couldn't find any mention of it in the manpage though.

---

This was added in [apk 2.3](https://git.alpinelinux.org/apk-tools/commit/src/apk.c?h=v2.3.0&id=92d6e99144a4b7227ad29c69fe10e97478bc63bb):

> #### apk: /etc/apk/interactive enables interactive mode for tty sessions
>
> In case someone prefers extra quesions while running apk in a
> terminal. The file is always from the real root; not from --root so
> that we will not accidentally enable interactive mode when in
> initramfs bootstrap.